# Can an assembly map CLR namespace to XAML namespace of it's referenced assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two WPF class Library project

Assembly_A
Assembly_B

Another WPF class library called `Assembly_AB` references the above two assemblies.

**AssemblyInfo.cs** file of `Assembly_AB` is below

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("abc.com/mycontrols", "Assembly_A.Namespace_a1", AssemblyName = "Assembly_A")]

[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("abc.com/mycontrols", "Assembly_A.Namespace_a2", AssemblyName = "Assembly_A")]

[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("abc.com/mycontrols", "Assembly_B.Namespace_b1", AssemblyName = "Assembly_B")]
```

Now my `WPF application` references `Assembly_AB` and I added xmlns prefix `xmlns:myCtrl`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
         xmlns:myCtrl="abc.com/mycontrols;assembly=Assembly_AB"
```

but I cannot access classes defined in Assembly_A and Assembly_B in XAML page.

I know if I add XmlnsDefinition to AssemblyInfo.cs file of Assembly_A and Assembly_B then it will work in WPF but I want to know if there is any way to map CLR namespace to XAML namespace of multiple assemblies by using another assembly?